# .Net Web API controller with different methods as per "GetFor"

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm coding a web api using .net and I doubt whether this is a proper way of creating a controller. The thing is that I have two different agreement documents to be loaded for two different kind of items. And I was thinking of putting both of them in the same controller and create two different methods in it. Let's say

```
[Route("visit/{visitId}/agreements/explanation")]
public Agreement GetVisitAgreement()
{
    return ...
}

[Route("viewing/{viewingId}/agreements/explanation")]
public Agreement GetViewingAgreement()
{
    return ...
}
```

But I'm thinking it can end up being similar to this controllers that have getby, getfor ... by dozens as I will need to add more cases. At the same time they use the same model (Agreement), so I'm not sure if it's a better design to have them in the Viewings an Visit's controllers or there's even another option I can't think of.

I would appreciate any heads up on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid code duplication, you can make an extra parameter telling if it's a visit or a viewing agreement :

```
[Route("agreements/{type}/{id}/explanation")]
public Agreement GetAgreement(string type, int id)
{
    // Some common operations

    if(type == "Visit")
    {
        // something specific concerning Visit agreement
    }
    else
    {
        // something specific concerning Viewing agreement
    }

    // return an agreement
}
```

Usually, you build controller around business domains. For example, a `UserController` managing user details, profiles, rights, etc. In your case, you can consider building an `AgreementController` dealing with different kind of agreements, according to your needs.

Comment: So, you think that's a clean enough call to expose. Yes, can be good. Actually I don't even need the id parameter as it's the same for all the items of one type. Thanks